# How do I offline check china or not given lat, lon data.

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude

Can I check china or not given lat, lon GPS Data?

If user stay in china then

STEP1. check lat/lon in offline func

If true

request googleGeocoding API for china

like this..

```
var chinaGoogleGeocoding="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;
```

else

var googleGeocoding="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;

Could you advising me?

I check http://maps.google.cn is working fine other country..but I want use it only user stay in china.

http://www.latlong.net

I think china's lat is start 37, end 47 and lon is start 123, end 110

so...

if((pos.coords.latitude>=37 && pos.coords.latitude<=47)&& (pos.coords.latitude>=110 && pos.coords.latitude<=123))
{

//china
var chinaGoogleGeocoding="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;
}else {
var googleGeocoding="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;
}

Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a country region can be defined by something like [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/)

Once you have a defined region to work with, you can compute if the coordinate you have received is inside the defined region for China.

Comment: I will try GeoJson. Thank you so much :)